# ExpoKit V32 missing assets

Tags: expo

My expoKit project is missing all assets (fonts and images).

When I run the app on my machine whether on Android or iOS and expo is in dev I get all the assets, if i switch expo to prod then the assets dissapear.

I did expo publish, then build an APK, the APK has all its assets (and is in the store).

I build an iOS app and put it on testflight it has no assets (Disaster!).

I am using expo + expokit v32, I know v33 is out but I'm struggling to update it.

Comment: you can try use : `expo optimize`

Answer (score 0):

I showed the same problem as you.

All my assets were stored locally, not from `uri`, but not from `APK`.

But I solved the problem. My solution went back to the moment when there was no problem, and started all over again. And when I created `APK` again, I successfully brought in assets.

Comment: im not exactly sure what you are saying i should do here?

Comment: You can try like me. Rollback to a place where there was no problem. And start all over again, and create APK.